# How do I get an access token from a Laravel web app that uses Passport as the Web Guard for use in Gatling Load Testing

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, token, laravel-passport, gatling

I have a web app whose api endpoints i want to test using Gatling.

I have set up the Gatling successfully. I have run the engine successfully against the recorded simulation. A report is generated.

However I notice that all the api endpoints in the report return KO meaning they failed. When I log the requests I can see that the endpoints return a 401: 'Unauthorized' meaning I need to include an Authorization element in the headers. From my research something like

`"Authorization" -> "Bearer ${access_token}"`

I take it this 'access_token' is the access_token that should be issued by passport from the web app. How do I get this access_token? I have login credentials to the app. I have tried using the login credentials as a query string appended to `the-web-app-url/oauth/authorize` but to know avail.

I am missing something about how this access token business works. I have the read the docs(Passport/Laravel) but I still dont get it. Help.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is learn about how security with token work.
Ideally, when you call login API, pass your login credentials, and if successful, the server will return you an access_token (sometimes in response data, sometimes in response header). After that you need to parse the response to get access_token and pass it to all requests after that, with the header: "Authorization" -> "Bearer ${access_token}"

Comment: @phapli Thank you for your response. Ok so I can see there's a variable called 'laravel_token' in the response header after login, is that what I am looking for? If it is should I then pass it to in the headers like : "Authorization" -> "Bearer thevalueoflaraventoken"?

Comment: Yes. But you should try it yourself and only you can confirm that work or not